# Time estimate for flooring, painting, closets, trim of 1500 SF home

Tags: flooring, painting, renovation

I recently received a time estimate from a potential contractor for renovating our 1500 SF 3BR apartment home.  Here are the major items:

- Remove existing hardwood floor
- Install new solid wood floor
- Install about 15 bi-fold doors on various closets
- All new trim
- Prime and painting of entire home including new doors and trim

No plumbing or electrical is involved.  The 1500 SF includes 3 small bedrooms, two hallways, two bathrooms, a small home office, small kitchen, medium-sized living room, small dining room.  He is telling me about 10-12 weeks.  Does this seem like a reasonable time estimate?

Comment: If your contractor is a 90 year old man doing the job himself then maybe 12 weeks.  Either your contractor plans on doing several jobs at once and will only be doing yours partially during those weeks or he is way over estimating.  A decent size crew (4-5 guys) could have this done in less than a week - given that you aren't missing anything.

Comment: We can't tell you what is reasonable or not without a whole lot of details.

Comment: If you are unsure of or don't like the specifics of an estimate, you can always get a 2nd or 3rd estimate to check the sanity of the 1st.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes new construction is easier in that you know exactly what the house is built of. If you're in an older house there may be more and more surprises which make the project harder and harder. The time estimate would vary depending on this contractor's crew size. It sounds like he has a very small crew (maybe of 1 or 2) and that is reflected in his estimate. It does sound a little long but there are a lot of variables and you're asking to have lots of work done. He's undoubtedly padded his time estimate just in case of surprises. So hopefully that's the longest it will be.